# How to find rows with only special characters on a field using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, regex

Here's the deal, i must find the rows, on which a determined field contains only special characters, I've been trying using regex, with no success.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col REGEXP '^[^[:alnum:][:space:]_]+$'`. BTW, what have you tried (since you say you were trying something).

Comment: So, did you have a chance of checking that?

Comment: But your LIKEs are fetching entries that *only contain* some non-alpha characters. You asked to return rows with *only special characters*. So, what is the requirement then?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. This question is indeed about return rows with only special characters, I'll fix my question and mark your answer as correct. Sorry about the delay.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col REGEXP '^[^[:alnum:][:space:]_]+$'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uX8rZ6/1).

The regex pattern breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^` - start of the [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches any character other than defined in this class

  - `[:alnum:]` - letters and digits
  - `[:space:]` - whitespace
  - `_` - underscore
- `]` - end of the negated character class
- `+` - the characters matched by the negated character class must be 1 or more occurrences
- `$` - end of string

Comment: check the edited question with the tryout of your answerd

Comment: @JorgeFerrari I noticed you had a follow up question. In fact, I do not know what the problem was, but for sure you cannot be surprised that `WHERE st_name LIKE '%.%' OR st_name LIKE '%(%'` is not returning the same result as `WHERE col REGEXP '^[^[:alnum:][:space:]]+$'` as `%` matches ANY char. Your LIKE can be re-written with regex as `WHERE st_name REGEXP '[.(]'`